# Update based on select to same table - AGAIN, and AGAIN

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In Microsoft SQL Server:

I have seen this question several times, but can't see anyone solving the problem:

```
UPDATE theTable t1
SET t1.col2 =
    (SELECT (10 * (col1 + col2))
     FROM theTable t2
     WHERE t1.busRelAccount = t2.busRelAccount
     AND t2.rowName = 'POS'
    )
WHERE t1.busRelAccount = t2.busRelAccount
AND t1.rowName = 'INVENTORY'
;
```

Anyone having solved this problem without using CURSOR and loop the table?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you're trying to do - but most likely, you could write your `UPDATE` statement much simpler - something like this:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.col2 = 10 * (t2.col1 + t2.col2)
FROM theTable t1
INNER JOIN theTable t2 ON t1.busRelAccount = t2.busRelAccount
WHERE 
    t1.rowName = 'INVENTORY'
    AND t2.rowName = 'POS'
;
```

Basically, you define a JOIN between the two tables (both being the same table, really) and you then define how to update the column of `t1` based on columns from `t2`